# Does Python have a built-in function for unindenting a multiline string?

Tags: python, string, indentation

Say I have the string

```
s = """
    Controller = require 'controller'

    class foo
        view: 'baz'
        class: 'bar'

        constructor: ->
            Controller.mix @
"""
```

Every line in the string now has a global 4 space indentation. If this string was declared inside a function, it would have a 8 space global indentation, etc.

Does Python have a function for removing the global left indentation of string?

I would like that function output to be:

```
Controller = require 'controller'

class foo
    view: 'baz'
    class: 'bar'

    constructor: ->
        Controller.mix @"
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Not a built-in function, but a function in the standard library:  [`textwrap.dedent()`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent)

```
>>> print(textwrap.dedent(s))

Controller = require 'controller'

class foo
    view: 'baz'
    class: 'bar'

    constructor: ->
        Controller.mix @
```

Comment: I did not know that one existed. Useful stuff. +1.

Comment: That's the fastest accumulation of up-votes I've ever seen for an answer

Comment: Source code of dedent here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/textwrap.py

Comment: The output of `textwrap.dedent(s)` starts with a newline and that is not asked for by the OP.

Comment: @Anthon: if you escape first newline as `s = """\ `, `dedent` will not produce first empty line.

Comment: @firegurafiku Of course not, it will not produce it because it is not there. The real problem is that it doesn't take it away when it **is there**, and that is what the OP asked for.

Comment: That's not a real problem for the OP, who already approved this answer.

Answer (score 26):

I know this question has already been answered but there's also this way:

```
import inspect

def test():
    t = """
    some text
    """

    return inspect.cleandoc(t)

print(test())
```

Comment: This is better than `textwrap.dedent` for some cases, because it also strips the trailing and leading newlines.

Comment: Was looking for this +1. Useful alternative to textwrap.dedent() . Only removes trailing newlines if indent is equal or less then global indent.

Comment: This is better than `textwrap.dedent` thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`textwrap.dedent()` is close to what you want, but it does not implement what you asked for, because it has a leading newline. You can either wrap `dedent` in a function that strips the leading newline from `s`:

```
def my_dedent(string):
    if string and string[0] == '\n':
        string = string[1:]
    return textwrap.dedent(string)
```

However `textwrap.dedent()` handles lines with just whitespace in special way that is OK if you are generating Python source from an indent multiline statement, where trailing whitespace is insignificant.

But in general it is inappropriate that `textwrap.dedent()` removes extra whitespace from lines with more whitespace than the 'maximum indent', removes whitespace from all whitespace lines and that it descards any whitespace before the closing `"""`, especially since this behaviour is [undocumented and done with non-transparent regular expressions](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/textwrap.py#l374).

Since I also generate non-Python source code where spaces are often significant I use the following routine. It doesn't handle TAB indentation, but it does give you the output you asked without leading newline, where `textwrap.dedent()` fails.

```
def remove_leading_spaces(s, strict=False):
    '''Remove the maximum common spaces from all non-empty lines in string

Typically used to remove leading spaces from all non-empty lines in a
multiline string, preserving all extra spaces.
A leading newline (when not useing '"""\') is removed unless the strict
argument is True.

Note that if you want two spaces on the last line of the return value 
without a newline, you have to use the max indentation + 2 spaces before 
the closing """. If you just input 2 spaces that is likely to be the 
maximum indent.
    '''
    if s and not strict and s[0] == '\n':
        s = s[1:]
    lines = s.splitlines(True) # keep ends
    max_spaces = -1
    for line in lines:
        if line != '\n':
            for idx, c in enumerate(line[:max_spaces]):
                if not c == ' ':
                    break
            max_spaces = idx + 1
    return ''.join([l if l == '\n' else l[max_spaces-1:] for l in lines])
```

Comment: OP didn't ask about leading newline nor removal of same. The simplest cure for leading newline is simply backslash after leading triple quote. (As already pointed out by @firegurafiku). There may be reasons to replace the supplied textwrap.dedent() with a custom function, but removal of newline, that can be just avoided with backslash, doesn't seem like a good one.

Comment: The **programmatic** removal of the initial newline is necessary to get from the OPs provided input to the requested out. There are always different ways to handle that, such as rewriting the string on one line with explicit backslashes. But the OP didn't ask for how to modify his input as you seem to suggest.

Comment: Seems that OP's task is not to process strings in general, it's how to write a multiline string literal with its source indented to match surrounding source indentation, yet not have the resulting string contain that indentation. OP's specific question was "Does Python have a function for removing the global left indentation of string?". The leading newline issue is relevant, but not required to be deleted by the requested function.  That said, your notes on dedent removing extra whitespace in some situations is a bit alarming, and would be interesting to know more about.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with a carriage return:

```
s = """
    \r Controller = require 'controller'
    \r
    \rclass foo
    \r    view: 'baz'
    \r    class: 'bar'
    \r
    \r    constructor: ->
    \r        Controller.mix @
    \r"""
```

Comment: This is a good solution to remove the leading spaces. Worked for me. Do not understand why someone will give -ve vote.

Comment: Definitely a creative solution!

Comment: This doesn't remove anything. It just makes it so when you print it to a terminal, it **looks like** stuff is removed!

Comment: As @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica points out, it only appears as if the whitespace has been removed. Writing the string to a file, for example, would include the bytes of hidden whitespace. It works in a pinch, with no 3rd party dependencies, but this is not a good solution for repeated use, or for anything other than printing the text to console.