# How can I do file handling?

Tags: python

## Problem

I'd like to delete the first space but keep the document format.

I'm trying to delete the space "XXXXXXXXXX" part and left-align keeping with the indentation format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a built-in function for unindenting a multiline string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157043/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-unindenting-a-multiline-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a builtin Python library called `textwrap` that can do this for you:

```
import textwrap

content = """\
    fizz buzz
  
     foo bar
"""

print(textwrap.dedent(content))
```

Output:

```
fizz buzz

 foo bar
```